# What's the better way to avoid adding a duplicate item to a list stored in database

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, postgresql

For one of the tables and its one of the columns in a postgresdb, that column is a list that stores comma-separated items.

The python code to currently populate an item in that list is using `UPDATE-SET` Postgres statements. If the item is already in list, it still adds it.

I have a basic version of adding it as first getting the list from database and then adding a new one only if not present else don't add. The problem with this approach is that it can run into race condition.
What is the alternative and optimized version to it.

Here is my current approach and need inputs to optimize this:

```
async def add(self, version, tag):

    get_sql = """
            SELECT tags
            FROM table_name
            WHERE id = $1

    """
    get_sql_args = [version]
    result = await self.execute_query_async(get_sql, get_sql_args, return_dataframe=True) # wrapper function on psycopg

    if result.iloc[0]['tags'] is None or tag not in result.iloc[0]['tags']:
        sql = """
            UPDATE table_name
            SET tags = COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) || $1
            WHERE id = $2
            RETURNING id, tags
        """
        sql_args = [tag, version]
        return await self.execute_query_async(sql, sql_args, return_dataframe=True)
    raise InvalidRequest('tag is already present.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the race condition, you could write an update query that checks if the new element already exists in the `JSONB` array before adding it. If the value already exists, the query does not add it.

In Postgres, you can use [the `?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to check if a string exists in an array.

I would suggest to change your logic so you pass a string to add to the array as a string instead of an array (as you are currently doing). This allows you to reuse the `$1` placeholder in the following query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET tags = COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_array($1)
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) ? $1;
RETURNING id, tags
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/738pUWEnrLdDdWqsnzMLGd/1)**:

```
--set up
CREATE TABLE table_name(id int primary key, tags jsonb);
INSERT INTO table_name(id) values(1);

-- first update
UPDATE table_name
SET tags = COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_array('foo')
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) ? 'foo';

--table content
SELECT * FROM table_name;

| id  | tags     |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | ["foo"]  |

-- attempt to update with the same id and tag element
UPDATE table_name
SET tags = COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) || jsonb_build_array('foo')
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT COALESCE(tags, '[]'::jsonb) ? 'foo';

-- existing tag element was not added
SELECT * FROM table_name;

| id  | tags     |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | ["foo"]  |
```